# ¿Cómo declaro una matriz cuadrada en Ruby?

Tags: ruby, matrices

Estoy tratando de rotar matrices rectangulares (cuadradas incluidas) en Ruby, pero me hallo con el problema de que no sé como declarar (sin inicializar de preferencia) una matriz de este tipo.

Investigando en internet encontré una clase aparentemente mágica llamada [Matrix](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) y estoy tratando de usarla con precarios resultados.

Mi mayor problema con esta librería es que no puedo usar algo como

```
rows = array.length
cols = array[0].length
returnedArray=Matrix.empty(cols, rows)
```

ya que uno de los parámetros para matrices rectangulares es que un parámetro sea cero.

Este es mi código hasta ahora:

```
require 'matrix'

def rotate(matrix, direction)
  if matrix.length == 0
    return matrix
  end
  if direction == "clockwise"
    return rotateRight(matrix)
  else
    return rotateLeft(matrix)
  end
end

def rotateRight(array)
    rows = array.length
    cols = array[0].length

    returnedArray=Matrix.empty(cols, 0)

    array.each_with_index do |e, row, col|
      returnedArray[col][(rows-1) - row] = e
    end
    return returnedArray
end

def rotateLeft(array)
  rows = array.length
  cols = array[0].length
  returnedArray=Matrix.empty(cols, 0)

  array.each_with_index do |e, row, col|
    returnedArray[(cols - 1) - col][row] = e
  end
  return returnedArray
end

matrix = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

rotate(matrix, 'counter-clockwise')
```

Lo que me produce un error:

> main.rb:32:in `-': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
>       from main.rb:32:in`block in rotateLeft'
>       from main.rb:31:in `each'
>       from main.rb:31:in`each_with_index'
>       from main.rb:31:in `rotateLeft'
>       from main.rb:10:in`rotate'
>       from main.rb:41:in `'

Actualización, he hecho la conversión de Matrix a Array usando el operador splat, pero aún así, se observa que la inserción en el arreglo no es la correcta, aquí un fragmento:

```
def rotateLeft(array)
  rows = array.length
  cols = array[0].length
  #returnedArray=Matrix.empty(cols, 0)
  returnedArray = Array.new(cols, Array.new(rows))

  matrixArray = Matrix[*array]

  puts matrixArray
  puts Matrix[*returnedArray]

  matrixArray.each_with_index do |e, row, col|
    puts "[#{row},#{col}]=#{e}"
    puts "returnedArray[#{cols - 1} - #{col} =>#{(cols - 1) - col}][#{row}] = #{e}"
    returnedArray[(cols - 1) - col][row] = e
    puts Matrix[*returnedArray]
  end
  puts Matrix[*returnedArray]
  return returnedArray
end
```

Salida:

```
Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Matrix[[, , ], [, , ], [, , ]]
[0,0]=1
returnedArray[2 - 0 =>2][0] = 1
Matrix[[1, , ], [1, , ], [1, , ]]
[0,1]=2
returnedArray[2 - 1 =>1][0] = 2
Matrix[[2, , ], [2, , ], [2, , ]]
[0,2]=3
returnedArray[2 - 2 =>0][0] = 3
Matrix[[3, , ], [3, , ], [3, , ]]
[1,0]=4
returnedArray[2 - 0 =>2][1] = 4
Matrix[[3, 4, ], [3, 4, ], [3, 4, ]]
[1,1]=5
returnedArray[2 - 1 =>1][1] = 5
Matrix[[3, 5, ], [3, 5, ], [3, 5, ]]
[1,2]=6
returnedArray[2 - 2 =>0][1] = 6
Matrix[[3, 6, ], [3, 6, ], [3, 6, ]]
[2,0]=7
returnedArray[2 - 0 =>2][2] = 7
Matrix[[3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7]]
[2,1]=8
returnedArray[2 - 1 =>1][2] = 8
Matrix[[3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 8]]
[2,2]=9
returnedArray[2 - 2 =>0][2] = 9
Matrix[[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]]
Matrix[[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]]
```

¿Qué necesito modificar para que funcione mi programa que rota matrices?

Comment: El error está aquí: `array.each_with_index do |e, row, col|`, dado que `each_with_index` te regresa solo **dos** variables, así que `e` tiene el valor del arreglo, `row` el índice y `col` tiene `nil`. ¿Exactamente qué buscas hacer en ese fragmento de código?

Comment: @Gerry ese código lo copié mira https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#each_with_index-method

Comment: El error está aquí: `Array.new(cols, Array.new(rows))` pues debería ser `Array.new(cols) { Array.new(rows) }`. La diferencia es que en el primer fragmento se crea un arreglo con `rows` y lo asigna a cada elemento de `cols`, pero es el mismo arreglo; en cambio, en el segundo se crea un arreglo distinto para cada elemento de `cols`.

Comment: Gracias! no me dí cuenta de ese detalle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actualización**

Para aprovechar la clase `Matrix` te recomiendo iniciar creando el objeto `Matrix` y pasarlo como argumento al método `rotate`; luego, en los métodos específicos para rotar (i.e. `rotate_left` y `rotate_right`), utiliza arreglos vacíos en lugar de objetos `Matrix` vacíos:

```
require 'matrix'

def rotate(matrix, direction)
  return matrix if matrix.empty?

  if direction == "clockwise"
    rotate_right(matrix)
  else
    rotate_left(matrix)
  end
end

def rotate_right(matrix)
  rows = matrix.row_size
  cols = matrix.column_size

  result_matrix = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(cols) }

  matrix.each_with_index do |e, row, col|
    result_matrix[col][(rows-1) - row] = e
  end

  result_matrix
end

def rotate_left(matrix)
  rows = matrix.row_size
  cols = matrix.column_size

  result_matrix = Array.new { rows, Array.new(cols) }

  matrix.each_with_index do |e, row, col|
    result_matrix[(cols - 1) - col][row] = e
  end

  result_matrix
end

matrix = Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

rotate(matrix, 'counter-clockwise')
#=> [[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]]

rotate(matrix, 'clockwise')
#=> [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Además, podrías limpiar un poco tu código (evitar la repetición) utilizando sólo una función y logrando el mismo resultado:

```
require 'matrix'

def rotate(matrix, direction)
  return matrix if matrix.empty?

  rows = matrix.row_size
  cols = matrix.column_size

  result_matrix = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(cols) }

  matrix.each_with_index do |e, row, col|
    if direction == "clockwise"
      result_matrix[col][(rows - 1) - row] = e
    else
      result_matrix[(cols - 1) - col][row] = e
    end
  end

  result_matrix
end

matrix = Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

rotate(matrix, 'counter-clockwise')
#=> [[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]]

rotate(matrix, 'clockwise')
#=> [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

---

Como opción alterna, podrías utilizar los métodos [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose) y [Array#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-reverse), a través de los cuales podrías lograr la rotación que buscas; por ejemplo:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

# Rotación a la izquierda:
matrix.map(&:reverse).transpose
#=> [[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]]

# Rotación a la derecha:
matrix.transpose.map(&:reverse)
#=> [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Sin embargo (tal como se resalta en los comentarios) **esta solución tiene un desempeño pobre** y no se recomienda para matrices grandes.

Comment: definitivamente esa debe de ser una muy mala práctica debido a su desempeño

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro En efecto, el desempeño puede ser pobre para matrices grandes, pero para matrices pequeñas no es problema.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro He actualizado la respuesta modificando tu código para que, utilizando tu lógica y aprovechando la clase `Matrix`, se muestre el resultado esperado.

Comment: A simple vista se puede decir que tu código unicamente funciona para matrices de 3x3

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Cierto, olvidé actualizar esos valores, pero ya he actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que no es la forma de asignar valores a un arreglo, por favor revisa, ya actualicé la pregunta

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro La asignación es correcta, el error estaba en la creación del arreglo; mira la respuesta actualizada, la cual puedes ver en acción [aquí](https://repl.it/repls/DearAgileMonitors).